# React Material UI responsive Grid with Card

Tags: css, datagridview, flexbox, material-ui, responsive

I am trying to create a responsive grid layout using cards that should have the same height including an image. I am using React and Material-UI.

I am fiddling around now for hours and cannot come up with a solution. The "flex" part seems super unintuitive to me. Please help.

It is a very small and simple code piece:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        cardGrid: {
            flexGrow: 1,
            paddingTop: 16,
        },
        card: {
            flex: 1,
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        cardActionArea: {
            flex: 1,
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
        },
        cardMedia: {
            height: '0',
            paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
        },
        cardContent: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: blue[600],
        },
        cardContentTitle: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: blue[400],
        },
        cardContentRating: {
            backgroundColor: blue[300],
        },
        cardContentDistance: {
            backgroundColor: blue[200],
        }
    }),
);

// ...

<Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="xl">
    <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="space-evenly"
        alignItems="stretch"
        spacing={2}
    >
        {
            dataList.map(data => (
                <Grid item
                      key={`GridItem-${data.id}`} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={2} xl={1}
                >
                    <Card className={classes.card}
                          onClick={handleCardClick}
                          key={`OverviewItem-${data.id}`}
                    >
                        <CardActionArea className={classes.cardActionArea}>
                            {
                                data.previewURL &&
                                <CardMedia
                                    className={classes.cardMedia}
                                    image={data.previewURL}
                                    title={data.title}
                                />
                            }
                            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" className={classes.cardContentTitle}>
                                    {data.title}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography className={classes.cardContentRating}>
                                    Some text
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography className={classes.cardContentDistance}>
                                    Some other text
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </CardActionArea>
                    </Card>
                </Grid>
            ))
        }
    </Grid>
</Container>
```

What I am trying to achieve:

- Image should be at the top of each card
- "Some text" and "Some other text" should get moved to the bottom

It seems like I have to write "flex:1" and "height:'100%'" multiple times when going down the tree and at some point it breaks completely like in following screenshot:

[image]

With the code snippet from above it looks like this:

[image]

What is the magic to simply expand the childs of a Grid Item to its maximum height and to still be able to align them as I want.

E.g. the entire card should stretch over the area of the Grid Item and the title part below the image should expand to move the image to the top and "Some text" and "Some other text" to the bottom.

Any hints/ideas are appreciated!

I was able to achieve what I wanted without a Card and without the image. But making the tree bigger and therefore the nesting deeper, breaks everything and I don't understand why.

Here is the simple snippet and the result:

```
<Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="xl">
    <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="space-evenly"
        alignItems="stretch"
        spacing={2}
    >
        {
            toiletOverviews.map(data => (
                <Grid item
                      key={`GridItem-${data.id}`} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={2} xl={1}
                >
                    <Box
                        display="flex"
                        flexDirection="column"
                        style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'purple'}}
                    >
                        <Typography
                            variant="h5"
                            style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: blue[800]}}
                        >
                            {data.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            style={{backgroundColor: blue[600]}}
                        >
                            Some text
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            style={{backgroundColor: blue[400]}}
                        >
                            Some other text
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            ))
        }
    </Grid>
</Container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The important part that I did not know is that `display:"flex"` is only applied to the current element and its direct children. For childrens of its childrens it will not be applied.

The solution now is to correctly apply it to all necessary elements. The sideeffect was that the image was no longer displayed. It had a width/height of zero. The fix here is to add `width:"100%"` to the CardMedia element.